# Routing to specific url from jquery load

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have defined custom route

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ListRoute",
                url: "List/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "List", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, type = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,  type = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And trying to load my partial page via jquery

```
$('#dvPartialFeatured').load("@Url.Action("DetailList", "List")");
```

here is my Controller in ListController:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {

            return View();
        }

public PartialViewResult DetailList(int id, int type)
        {
            var objSearchModels = new SearchModels()
            {
                SubCategory = id,
                Type = type
            };
            return PartialView("~/Views/ProductListing/_PartialProductListing.cshtml", ProductListingService.PopulateSearchList(objSearchModels));
        }
```

But its redirecting to Index, I even tried using

```
$('#dvPartialFeatured').load("@Url.HttpRouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "List", Action = "DetailList" })", {id:1, type:2});
```

However when I remove custom route ListRoute it is working fine

Comment: Your link does not include the `type` property (`id` can be omitted as it is optional in the routing), therefore it does not match the signature of the method so you are being redirected to the default.

Comment: I added type as optional but still the result is same

Comment: dont you need ``action = "DetailList"`` instead  ``action = "Index"``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad actually I want to go to DetailList rather than Index

Comment: ``DetailList`` needs two parameters

Comment: @EhsanSajjad added but still same result

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added it but still same

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out in a test application with  your code on and this url seems to hit `DetailList` action with proper parameter binding and I kept everything the same:

```
/List/DetailList/1?type=2
```

Here is the [download link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/f8rkwc) to the sample application I tried it on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include a type parameter in your routes (as there is no segment for it, you don't provide a default value for it and most actions may not require it), so you can define them as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ListRoute",
    url: "List/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "List", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(                
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this definition, if you want to target your `DetailList` method of the List controller, you need to provide the id and type parameters(as they are non-nullable parameters of the controller method).

However if you want to target the `Index` method in the List controller, you don't need to provide an id parameter. This is because it is optional in the route and declared as a string in the controller method (so it will be null if called without an id)

For example:

- The line `@Url.Action("DetailList", "List", new {id = 1, type = 2})` generates the url `/List/DetailList/1?type=2`, which will end in the `DetailList` action of the `ListController`.
- The line `@Url.Action("Index", "List", new { id = 1 })` will generate the url `/List/1` (using your *ListRoute* route), which will end in the `Index` action of the `ListController`.
- The line `@Url.Action("Index", "List")` will generate the url `/List` (using your *ListRoute* route), which will end in the `Index` action of the `ListController`, with a null value for id.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was just getting &amp concatenated, so used Html.Raw and its okay now, anyways thanks